# material ui: reactjs: Grid how to add margin

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following Grid in material-ui reactjs

```
    <Grid container direction="row" justify="flex-end" alignItems="center">
      <Grid item>
        <Paper>
          test
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Paper>
          test
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs>
        <Paper>
          testing
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

It shows as

[image]

Now i want some gap between the two containers.

I tried

```
    <Grid container direction="row" justify="flex-end" alignItems="center">
      <Grid item>
        <Paper>
          test
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Paper>
          test
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container m={2}>
      <Grid item xs>
        <Paper>
          testing
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Still i get the same

[image]

Comment: Try: `<Grid container spacing={2}`. See [Spacing](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#spacing)

Comment: but i want to add only top margin

Comment: If you use MUI v5. You can use [`Stack`](https://next.material-ui.com/components/stack/#main-content) to set the space between children only. Otherwise, wrap the child in a `Box` and set margin top like this: `<Box mt={2}`

Comment: you mean wrap `<Grid container>` inside a `<Box mt={2}>`

Comment: Put `<Grid container m={2}>` inside `Box` and remove `m={2}` as it's not a valid props of `Grid`. `m` (margin) is a [system property](https://next.material-ui.com/system/properties/). Only `Box` supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline style for it, but if you don't want to use inline style, put them inside another container and add spacing to the first container

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid container item xs={12} direction="row" justify="flex-end" alignItems="center">
      <Grid item>
        <Paper>
          test
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Paper>
          test
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container item xs={12}>
      <Grid item>
        <Paper>
          testing
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: ok, i only want spacing between, but not side